# Longest alphabetical substring - where to begin

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

I am working on the "longest alphabetical substring" problem from the popular MIT course.  I have read a lot of the information on SO about how to code it but I'm really struggling to make the leap conceptually.  The finger exercises preceding it were not too hard.  I was wondering if anyone knows of any material out there that would really break down the problem solving being employed in this problem.  I've tried getting out a pen and paper and I just get lost.  I see people employing "counters" of sorts, or strings that contain the "longest substring so far" and when I'm looking at someone else's solution I can understand what they've done with their code, but if I'm trying to synthesize something of my own it's just not clicking.

I even took a break from the course and tried learning via some other books, but I keep coming back to this problem and feel like I need to break through it.  I guess what I'm struggling with is making the leap from knowing some Python syntax and tools to actually employing those tools organically for problem solving or "computing".

Before anyone points me towards it, I'm aware of the course materials that are aimed at helping out.  I've seen some videos that one of the TAs made that are somewhat helpful but he doesn't really break this down.  I feel like I need to pair program it with someone or like... sit in front of a whiteboard and have someone walk me step by step and answer every stupid question I would have.

For reference, the problem is as follows:

> Assume s is a string of lower case characters.
>
> Write a program that prints the longest substring of s in which the letters occur in alphabetical order. For example, if s = 'azcbobobegghakl', then your program should print
>
> Longest substring in alphabetical order is: beggh
>
> In the case of ties, print the first substring. For example, if s = 'abcbcd', then your program should print
>
> Longest substring in alphabetical order is: abc

I know that it's helpful to post code but I don't have anything that isn't elsewhere on SO because, well, that's what I've been playing with in my IDE to see if I can understand what's going on.  Again, not looking for code snippets - more some reading or resources that will expand upon the logic being employed in this problem.  I'll post what I do have but it's not complete and it's as far as I get before I start feeling confused.

```
s = 'azcbobobegghakl'

current = s[0]
longest = s[0]

for letter in range(0, len(s) -1):
    if s[letter + 1] >= s[letter]:
        current.append(s[letter + 1])
        if len(current) > len(longest):
            longest = current
        else:
            current =
```

Sorry for formatting errors, still new to this.  I'm really frustrated with this problem.

Comment: @ScipioneSarlo he has, look at the bottom

Comment: I recommend starting with trying to implement a simpler, slower algorithm that gets the job done.  You're looking for an alphabetical substring, well, it must start somewhere, and it must end somewhere after it starts -- so something that would work is to try every possible substring, and test whether it is alphabetical; if so, also check if it's longer than the longest one you have seen so far; if it passes both of these tests, make it the current "champion".  If that seems too hard right now, I suggest a simpler problem: finding the maximum number in a list of numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are struggling with the concepts and logic behind solving this problem, I would recommend perhaps stepping back a little and going through easier coding tutorials and interactive exercises. You might also enjoy experimenting with JavaScript, where it might be easier to get creative right from the outset, building out snippets and/or webpages that one can immediately interact with in the browser. Then when you get more fun coding vocabulary under your belt, the algorithmic part of it will seem more familiar and natural. I also think letting your own creativity and imagination guide you can be a very powerful learning process.

Let's forget about the alphabetical part for the moment. Imagine we have a bag of letters that we pull out one at a time without knowing which is next and we have to record the longest run of `R`s in a row. How would you do it? Let's try to describe the process in words, then pseudocode.

We'll keep a container for the longest run we've seen so far and another to check the current run. We pull letters until we hit two `R`s in a row, which we put it in the "current" container. The next letter is not an `R`, which means our run ended. The "longest-so-far" run is empty so we pour the "current" container in it and continue. The next four letters are not `R`s so we just ignore them. Then we get one `R`, which we put in "current" and then an `H`. Our run ended again but this time our one `R` in "current" was less than the two we already have in "longest-so-far" so we keep those and empty "current."

We get an `A`, a `B`, and a `C`, and then a run of five `R`s, which we put into the "current" container one by one. Our bag now contains the last letter, a `T`. We see that our run ended again and that "current" container has more than the "longest-so-far" container so we pour out "longest" and replace its contents with the five `R`s in "current." That's it, we found the longest run of `R`s in the bag. (If we had more runs, each time one ended we'd choose whether to replace the contents of "longest-so-far.")

In pseudocode:

```
// Initialise
current <- nothing
longest <- nothing

for letter in bag:
  if letter == 'R':
    add 'R' to current
  else:
    if there are more letters
    in current than longest:
      empty longest and pour
      in letters from current
    otherwise:
      empty current to get ready
      for the next possible run
```

Now the alphabetical stipulation just slightly complicates our condition. We will need to keep track of the most recent letter placed in "current," and in order for a run to continue, its not seeing another of the same letter that counts. Rather, the next letter has to be "greater" (lexicographically) than the last one we placed in current; otherwise the run ends and we perform our quantity check against "longest-so-far."

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write this out.  I suppose one thing I've been doing in my psuedocode that isn't really effective is trying to avoid abstraction for some reason - I think the approach you show of really just focusing on the concept at hand is helpful.  I'm still working on this problem, will report back soon.

Comment: I forgot to follow up, but this line of thinking really helped me out with this problem.  I spent a bit of time stepping away from it and just getting more comfortable with loops in general before coming back to this problem.  Your psuedocode was really helpful and I wanted to say thanks again for taking the time to help me out!

Answer (score 4):

You're almost there in your example, just needs a little tweaking

```
s = 'azcbobobegghakl'

longest = [s[0],]  # make them lists so we can manipulate them (unlike strings)
current = [s[0],]

for letter in range(0, len(s) -1):
    if s[letter + 1] >= s[letter]:
        current.append(s[letter + 1])
        if len(current) > len(longest):
            longest = current
    else:
        current = [s[letter+1],]  # reset current if we break an alphabetical chain

longest_string = ''.join(longest)  # turn out list back into a string
```

output of `longest_string`:

```
'beegh'
```

Comment: for "ihabtylmnrpqrs" output should be "pqrs" but it is giving "abty"

Comment: @ashishpal I mean, neither of those results is wrong. It depends on whether you want the first or last encountered equal length longest. Changing the `>` to a `>=` will solve that.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to reply but I guess what I'm struggling with is more the concepts... I guess I'm obviously struggling with the code too but I was hoping more for some reading material or similar to help make the concepts stick.  I don't even know the right words to ask about the concepts being employed.  All the same, thanks

Comment: Ah well that's not really stack overflows place for that. http://reddit.com/r/learnpython may be more useful for you

Answer (score 1):

Generally, it is easier to create a listing of all possibilities from the input, and then filter the results based on the additional logic needed. For instance, when finding longest substrings, all substrings of the input can be found, and then only elements that are valid sequences are retained:

```
def is_valid(d):
  return all(d[i] <= d[i+1] for i in range(len(d)-1))

def longest_substring(s):
  substrings = list(filter(is_valid, [s[i:b] for i in range(len(s)) for b in range(len(s))]))
  max_length = len(max(substrings, key=len)) #this finds the length length of the longest valid substring, to be used if a tie is discovered
  return [i for i in substrings if len(i) == max_length][0]

l = [['abcbcd', 'abc'], ['azcbobobegghakl', 'beggh']]
for a, b in l:
  assert longest_substring(a) == b

print('all tests passed')
```

Output:

```
all tests passed
```

Answer (score 1):

One way of dealing with implementation complexity is, for me, to write some unit tests: at some point, if I can't figure out from "reading the code" what is wrong, and/or what parts are missing, I like to write unit tests which is an "orthogonal" approach to the problem (instead of thinking "how can I solve this?" I ask myself "what tests should I write to verify it works ok?").

Then, by running the tests I can observe how the implementation behaves, and try to fix problems "one by one", i.e concentrate on making that next unit test pass.

It's also a way of "cutting a big problem in smaller problems which are easier to reason about".

Answer (score 0):

```
s = 'azcbobobeggh'

ls = [] #create a new empty list

for i in range(len(s) - 1): # iterate s from index 0 to index -2
    if s[i] <= s[i+1]: # compare the letters
        ls.append(s[i]) # after comparing them, append them to the new list
    else:
        ls.append(s[i])
        ls.append('mark') # place a 'mark' to separate them into chunks by order
ls.append(s[-1]) # get back the index -1 that missed by the loop

# at this point here ls:
# ['a', 'z', 'mark', 'c', 'mark', 'b', 'o', 'mark', 'b', 'o', 'mark', 'b', 'e', 'g', 'g', 'h']

ls = str(''.join(ls)) # 'azmarkcmarkbomarkbomarkbeggh'
ls = ls.split('mark') # ['az', 'c', 'bo', 'bo', 'beggh']
res = max(ls, key=len) # now just find the longest string in the list

print('Longest substring in alphabetical order is: ' + res)

# Longest substring in alphabetical order is: beggh
```

Comment: Please explain your answer, do not post just code blocks.

Comment: @dorukerenaktas Thank you for your comment. I have edited my answer.