# List of possible substrings where letters alphabetical. Recursively

Tags: python, recursion

I came across this [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/194169/a-program-that-prints-the-longest-substring-of-s-in-which-the-letters-occur-in-a) and this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50366484/longest-alphabetical-substring-where-to-begin?rq=1) both pointing to the same exercise. I want to do the same thing but using recursion.

I would like to return the list of possible substrings within the full string that satisfy this condition:
All letters are in alphabetical order.

eg if the full string was `'abca'` the function should return `['a', 'b', 'c' , 'ab', 'bc', 'abc']` in any order.

My function below tries to get the number of substrings of length `num` from the full string `s`. It isn't working. the result is an empty list always. It never enters the first `if` statement. Please point out where I'm wrong. The statement I use to call the function is:

`print(recursion('abca',3))`

```
def recursion(s, num):
    wrds = []    

    if num > 1:
        if num <= len(s) - 1:
            num -= 1
            wrds.extend(recursion(s, num))
            return wrds
        else:
            for starting_position in range(len(s) - num):
                for counter in range(num):
                    if s[starting_position + counter] < s[starting_position+counter - 1]:
                        wrds.append(s[:(starting_position + counter + 1)])
                        return wrds
    else:
        return wrds
```

Comment: What isn't working exactly? Do you get an error (if so, can you show us the full traceback)? Is the result wrong (if so, what is it).

Comment: Corrected my question. The result is always an empty list

Comment: how do you call `recusion` first time?

Comment: print(recursion('abca',3))

Comment: `num <= len(s) - 1`, `num` will never be greater than `len(s)-1` or equal  to it, hence your inner `else` statement will never be executed.

Comment: I'm confused as to why your example output for `'abca'` does not include the last character, `a`, as a valid substring. It fits the definition of a "possible substring within the full string that satisfies this condition: All letters are in alphabetical order." And it is a different substring from the first `a` character, which you do list in the example output.

Comment: That's true @Gilad. I was only looking for the distinct possibilities. Since `a` is already an option from the first letter, I excluded it.

Comment: Ah, you might want to clarify that in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can write a pure recursion (one function, one argument) by assuming that substrings will be presented in increasing length starting from the first character.

Python code:

```py
def f(s):
  if len(s) < 2:
    return [s]

  rest = f(s[1:])

  if s[0] > s[1]:
    return [s[0]] + rest

  else:
    updates = [s[0]]
    i = 0

    while i < len(rest) and i < len(rest[i]):
      updates.append(s[0] + rest[i])
      i = i + 1

    return updates + rest
```

Output:

```
 > f('abca')
=> ['a', 'ab', 'abc', 'b', 'bc', 'c', 'a']

 > f('cdeabc')
=> ['c', 'cd', 'cde', 'd', 'de', 'e', 'a', 'ab', 'abc', 'b', 'bc', 'c']
```

Comment: There must be a more elegant way to write it but I couldn't find any.

Comment: what is the  i < len(rest[i]) doing exactly?

Comment: @JonJavaK we need a way to identify which are the substrings in the "rest" list that are appropriate to prepend `s[0]` to. This check confirms that they are increasing in length. If their length stops increasing, that means we hit the next group of substrings that starts one character removed, which we do not want to prepend `s[0]` to.

Answer (score 2):

This is not the best solution for this, especially in Python. Nevertheless, in order to give you the idea, I wanted to give you a solution based on your code.

Basically, in `while=True` loop, I set my initial `starting_position` to 0 and start taking substrings of length `num`, until I reach out of bounds, i.e. `num+starting_position>len(s)`. After that point, I exit the `while=True` loop and proceed to next reoccuring function.

```
def recursion(s, num):
    wrds = []

    if num < 1 or num > len(s)-1:
        return wrds

    starting_position = 0
    while True:
        counter = 0
        if num+starting_position<=len(s):
            next_substring = s[starting_position:(starting_position + num)]
            print("appending %s stpos: %d" % (next_substring, starting_position))
            wrds.append(next_substring)
            counter += 1
        else:
            print("out of limit! exiting while loop.")
            break
        starting_position += 1
        if starting_position == len(s):
            break
    wrds.extend(recursion(s, num-1))
    return wrds


arr = recursion("abca", 3)
print(arr)
```

prints

```
appending abc stpos: 0
appending bca stpos: 1
out of limit! exiting while loop.
appending ab stpos: 0
appending bc stpos: 1
appending ca stpos: 2
out of limit! exiting while loop.
appending a stpos: 0
appending b stpos: 1
appending c stpos: 2
appending a stpos: 3
['abc', 'bca', 'ab', 'bc', 'ca', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a']
```

EDIT: If you want to find alphabetically sorted substrings, I also wrote this solution. Basically, again, I traverse every substring of window size `num`, starting from `starting_position`. However, I traverse char by char in order to validate that `next_substring_candidate` is an alphabetically sorted word. I hope that code output will help you understand clearly.

```
def recursion(s, num):
    wrds = []

    if num < 1 or num > len(s)-1:
        return wrds

    starting_position = 0
    while True:
        counter = 0
        if num+starting_position<=len(s):
            next_substring_candidate = s[starting_position]
            print("starting with %s!" % next_substring_candidate)
            for i in range(1, num):
                next_letter = s[starting_position+i]
                previous_letter = s[starting_position+i-1]
                print("next letter: %s, previous letter: %s" % (next_letter, previous_letter))
                if next_letter >= previous_letter:
                    print("yes! adding next letter (%s) to word (%s)!" % (next_letter,next_substring_candidate))
                    next_substring_candidate += next_letter
                else:
                    print("no! next letter (%s) is smaller than previous (%s)!" % (next_letter, previous_letter))
                    break

            if len(next_substring_candidate) != num:
                print("skipping this substring because not enough length! (%s)" % next_substring_candidate)
                starting_position += 1
                if starting_position == len(s):
                    break
                continue
            if next_substring_candidate not in wrds:
                print("adding new substring to list! (%s)" % next_substring_candidate)
                wrds.append(next_substring_candidate)
            counter += 1
        else:
            print("out of limit! exiting while loop.")
            break
        starting_position += 1
        if starting_position == len(s):
            break
    wrds.extend(recursion(s, num-1))
    return wrds


arr = recursion("abca", 3)
print(arr)
```

Watch the code output to see how it works:

```
yilmazali@yilmazali:~/stackoverflow_tests$ python3 sotestrecur.py 
starting with a!
next letter: b, previous letter: a
yes! adding next letter (b) to word (a)!
next letter: c, previous letter: b
yes! adding next letter (c) to word (ab)!
adding new substring to list! (abc)
starting with b!
next letter: c, previous letter: b
yes! adding next letter (c) to word (b)!
next letter: a, previous letter: c
no! next letter (a) is smaller than previous (c)!
skipping this substring because not enough length! (bc)
out of limit! exiting while loop.
starting with a!
next letter: b, previous letter: a
yes! adding next letter (b) to word (a)!
adding new substring to list! (ab)
starting with b!
next letter: c, previous letter: b
yes! adding next letter (c) to word (b)!
adding new substring to list! (bc)
starting with c!
next letter: a, previous letter: c
no! next letter (a) is smaller than previous (c)!
skipping this substring because not enough length! (c)
out of limit! exiting while loop.
starting with a!
adding new substring to list! (a)
starting with b!
adding new substring to list! (b)
starting with c!
adding new substring to list! (c)
starting with a!
['abc', 'ab', 'bc', 'a', 'b', 'c']
yilmazali@yilmazali:~/stackoverflow_tests$
```

Comment: How are `'bca'` and `'ca'` in increasing alphabetical order?

Comment: OP says ‘in any order’

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood. Quote from the question: "return the list of possible substrings within the full string that satisfy this condition: All letters are in alphabetical order." I think "in any order" is referring to the order of the substrings in the returned list.

Comment: oh, I see. Well, if you want to do that, instead of taking `next_substring` right away, try to iterate characters one by one: starting from `starting_position`, window size = `num`. I will edit my answer in a minute.

Answer (score 1):

OK so I'm just going to give you a solution *that doesn't rely on recursion* (in general recursion is bad in python due to the large overhead of function calls). It's not based on yours but hopefully you get whats going on

```
def alph_substr(s):

    all_substr = []
    itr = iter(s)
    prev = next(itr)
    current_substr = [prev]

    for char in itr:
        if char >= prev:
            current_substr.append(char)
        else:
            all_substr.append(current_substr)
            current_substr = [char]
        prev = char

    all_substr.append(current_substr)

    all_substr = [''.join(substr) for substr in all_substr]
    for substr in all_substr.copy():
        for length in range(1, len(substr)):
            for index in range(len(substr) - length + 1):
                all_substr.append(substr[index:index+length])

    return set(all_substr)
```

And testing:

```
alph_substr('helloworld')
```

outputs

```
{'d',
 'e',
 'el',
 'ell',
 'ello',
 'ellow',
 'h',
 'l',
 'll',
 'llo',
 'llow',
 'lo',
 'low',
 'o',
 'or',
 'ow',
 'r',
 'w'}
```

Comment: Isn't your example output missing the following? `['ello', 'llow', 'l' (the second one), 'low', 'ow', 'w', 'o' (the second one), 'r', 'l' (the third one), 'd']`

Comment: I'm missing some yes. Had a brain fart and forgot `range` is stop exclusive. Fixed now. I deliberately get rid of repetitions by calling `set`.

Comment: it's like someone yelling it across a canyon with the echo reverberating

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for your input. From your answers I was able to find a solution:

```
def recursion(s,num):
    wrds = []    

    if num<1:
        return wrds

    for starting_position in range(len(s)-num):
            for counter in range(num):
                if s[starting_position+counter]>=s[starting_position+counter-1]:
                    wrds.append(s[starting_position:starting_position+counter+1])
                else:
                    wrds.extend(recursion(s[1:],num))
                    return wrds

    wrds.extend(recursion(s,num-1))
    return list(set(wrds))
```

Answer (score 0):

I was not willing to give you direct solution. But while debug your code, try this:

```
def generateComb(s,num):
    wrds = []    
    print "s ", s
    x = len(s)
    for i in range(1 << x):
        str = [s[j] for j in range(x) if (i & (1 << j))]
        if len(str) > num:
            break
        print "".join(str)



generateComb("abcd", 2)
```